# Laravel Horizon - Jobs getting stucked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-horizon

we're using Laravel 8.x and we've just switched our queue driver from database to redis/horizon. Now we're getting some strange behavior with some jobs.

The Job itself does converting stuff over some time between a few minutes up to 90 minutes. With the database-driver the job is executed properly. With horizon the job is executed for some time and then seems to get stucked. We've tested the job many times with the same payload and it get stucked at different runtimes and get marked as failed after the timeout (with the same timestamp as start).

The logfile of supervisor contains the following:

```
[2022-01-07 18:08:33][b69e5cf9-4f88-4005-a5c4-4722e46fe7d0] Processing: App\Jobs\ConvertJob
[2022-01-07 18:08:33][b69e5cf9-4f88-4005-a5c4-4722e46fe7d0] Failed:     App\Jobs\ConvertJob
```

The (other) logfiles doesn't contain any (other) errors :-/

Our config for horizon looks like this (just the relevant parts):

```
'memory_limit' => 64,

    'defaults' => [
      'converter' => [
          'connection' => 'redis',
          'queue' => ['convert'],
          'balance' => 'auto',
          'maxProcesses' => 1,
          'memory' => 128,
          'tries' => 1,
          'nice' => 0,
      ],
      'worker' => [
          'connection' => 'redis',
          'queue' => ['default'],
          'balance' => 'auto',
          'maxProcesses' => 1,
          'memory' => 128,
          'tries' => 1,
          'nice' => 0,
      ],
    ],

    'environments' => [
      'local' => [
        'converter' => [
          'minProcesses' => 4,
          'maxProcesses' => 9,
          'balanceMaxShift' => 3,
          'balanceCooldown' => 2,
        ],
        'worker' => [
          'maxProcesses' => 6,
          'balanceMaxShift' => 2,
          'balanceCooldown' => 3,
        ]
      ],

    ],
```

Supervisor config:

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /app/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=%(ENV_SUPERVISOR_USER)s
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/app/logs/sv-horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=5400
```

Queue config:

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'queue',
    'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
    'retry_after' => 5430,
    'block_for' => null,
    'after_commit' => false,
],
```

The Job itself sets tries to 1, timeout to 5400 seconds and failOnTimeout true.

Maybe anyone of you can give me a hint?

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes errors are not logged to storage/log/laravel or the configured log channel but is written to stderr and then the error can be found somewhere else, such as /var/log/syslog or /var/log/php-error.log. While not a reply to the asked question. The first step is probably to figure out why and where it fails.

By the way, 64mb memory limit is very little. I benchmarked a job the other day and without even starting processing that php script was taking about ~75mb. I dont think below 100mb should be concidered, especially for such a long running job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I increased `memory_limit=500` , as suggested by @patrik-grinsvall, problem was solved